# What is the difference between `return iter()` and `yield from` in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

What is the difference between `return iter()` and `yield from` in my case? Or is my code correct?

I want my class can be iterated multiple times.

See the code below:

```py
from typing import Iterable

class My_yield_from:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
        self.tag = 'happy'

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.data

print('My_yield_from is Iterable?', isinstance(My_yield_from(), Iterable))

class My_iter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
        self.tag = 'happy'

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

print('My_iter is Iterable?', isinstance(My_iter(), Iterable))
```

And the test codes:

```py
my = My_yield_from()
print('first loop')
for i in my:
    print(i)

print('second loop')
for i in my:
    print(i)

print('another iter')
it = iter(my)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
try:
    print(next(it))
except StopIteration:
    print('StopIteration')

print('another iter')
it = iter(my)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
try:
    print(next(it))
except StopIteration:
    print('StopIteration')

print('two iters')
it1 = iter(my)
it2 = iter(my)
print(next(it1))
print(next(it2))
print(next(it1))
print(next(it2))
print(next(it1))
print(next(it2))
```

Comment: `yield from` lets you have other statements after it. `return iter()` will make anything following unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `return` and `yield from` will be like the difference between `return` and `yield` in that `return` exits the function immediately on being called and returns to its caller but `yield` and `yield from` pass control to a calling iterating function or method before control returns to the method a value was yielded.

I threw together with this demo:

```
RANGE_TO_ITERATE = range(12)

def just_return_list():
    print("entering return_list")
    return iter(RANGE_TO_ITERATE)
    # Like Matszwecja points out, a print
    # statement here would be unreachable.

def generate_with_yield():
    for num in RANGE_TO_ITERATE:
        print(f"about to yield {num}..")
        yield num
        print(" ..yielded.")

def generate_with_yield_from():
   print("about to yield from..")
   yield from RANGE_TO_ITERATE
   print("\ndone yielding from")
```

`return` and `yield from` are similar in that you only call them once. There's no need to iterate through individual elements like with `yield`.

If I test `return`:

```
print("Demonstrate return iter..")
for x in just_return_list():
   print(f"found {x}", end=", ")
print("\ndone demonstrating return iter")
```

It enters and exits `just_return_list` before writing any elements.

```
Demonstrate return iter..
entering return_list
found 0, found 1, found 2, found 3, found 4, found 5, found 6, found 7, found 8, found 9, found 10, found 11, 
done demonstrating return iter
```

If I test `yield from`:

```
print("Demonstrate yield from..")
for x in generate_with_yield_from():
   print(f"found {x}",end=", ")
print("\ndone demonstrating yield from")
```

The main visible difference is that we can see print statements on entering **and exiting** the generator function.

```
Demonstrate yield from..
about to yield from..
found 0, found 1, found 2, found 3, found 4, found 5, found 6, found 7, found 8, found 9, found 10, found 11, 
done yielding from

done demonstrating yield from
```

With `yield` I see more transfer of control:

```
print("Demonstrate yield..")
for x in generate_with_yield():
   print(f"found {x}",end=", ")
print("\ndone demonstrating yield")
```

```
Demonstrate yield..
about to yield 0..
found 0,  ..yielded.
about to yield 1..
found 1,  ..yielded.
about to yield 2..
found 2,  ..yielded.
about to yield 3..
found 3,  ..yielded.
about to yield 4..
found 4,  ..yielded.
about to yield 5..
found 5,  ..yielded.
about to yield 6..
found 6,  ..yielded.
about to yield 7..
found 7,  ..yielded.
about to yield 8..
found 8,  ..yielded.
about to yield 9..
found 9,  ..yielded.
about to yield 10..
found 10,  ..yielded.
about to yield 11..
found 11,  ..yielded.

done demonstrating yield
```

Comment: So if I just want to implement `for x in MyClass_object: do()` and make MyClass_object iterable multiple times, can `return iter()` and `yield from` be considered technically equivalent?